# How to make mod_rewrite for multiple web app in one sub domain

Tags: angular, apache, .htaccess, lumen

I have a problem on rewrite rule in .htaccess, mainly because I never personally use Apache. Here is my folder

`--root-folder
-------------index.html
-------------another_app0_folder
-------------------------------index.html
-------------another_app1_folder
-------------------------------index.html
-------------another_app2_folder
--------------------------------public
--------------------------------------index.php`

Basically I want to access those apps on one domain.
Let's say if I want to access *mydomain.com* that will be my root folder, then if I want to access app 1 that will be mydomain.com/app1.
I found the trickiest part is the last app, because I want to access it one 1 /, also I want to rewrite the URL, I understand if I can rename the folder with whatever but I want to make the URL after / is not the name of the folder. Can anyone help me on that?

Additional info: the root folder, app 0, and app 1 are Angular 4 projects and app 2 is a Lumen project

> PS: Found out recently, renaming folder made the browser redirects me to the root folder every time I hit refresh

Comment: can you explain a little more? Which is the URL you want to rewrite? Show the example URL that you want to rewrite to. App0 and app1 should just load as normal by going to those sub directories.

Comment: @PanamaJack my sub domain is like sub.domain.com. So, 1. sub.domain.com is equal to root folder, 2. sub.domain.com/folder_name_of_app1 will be sub.domain.com/app1, and so on, I completely understand that subfolder name would be sufficient to create URL, but I don't want to do that.